# grep to search error_log and email only when results found?

Tags: grep

Is it possible to use Grep to search a file and send a email based on the results?

I have been using

```
grep SEARCHSTRING /logs/error_log | mailx -s subject name@emailaddress.co.uk
```

But I don't want it to send an email when Null it met (No results found)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `mailx` if the `grep` command returns success i.e. match is found:

```
body="$(grep SEARCHSTRING /logs/error_log)" && echo "$body" | mailx -s subject name@emailaddress.co.uk
```

Saving the output of `grep` (if any) to variable `body`, if the `grep` command succeeds then `mailx` will be run with `$body` as the body of the mail.

Answer (score 2):

```
output="$(grep SEARCHSTRING /logs/error_log)"
test -n "$output" && echo "$output" | mailx -s subject name@emailaddress.co.uk
```

Comment: Thank you. I never considered doing it like this, i was trying to use a Temp file to populate the results and only email when its not empty.
Using the variable was a great idea. 
Using your example :) Thanks
Changes for a one liner so can just add a Cron <BR>

data=$(grep 'SEARCHSTRING' logs/error_log) ; [[ -n "$data" ]] && mail -s 'dd' name@emailaddress.co.uk <<< "$data"